$\# f^{-1}(y)$ for compact, connected manifolds
I'm not sure if this question has been asked before and I feel like it might be trivial... I recently proved that for compact manifolds $M$ and $N$ and a smooth map $f: M \to N$, if $y$ is a regular value, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite. Now I also saw that this number $k = \# f^{-1}(y) $ is locally constant. So now I'm wondering whether, if $M$ and $N$ are also assumed to be connected, does this make $\#f^{-1}(y)$ globally constant? Intuitively, I think it does, because every $y'$ that is 'close enough' to some $y$ give the same number $k$ and connectedness means that every point is somehow 'close enough' to all other points. But I can't seem to prove this formally. I had some ideas about proving this by contradiction, maybe using the fact that if there exist $k_1 \neq k_2$, then $N$ has to have at least two disjoint open sets? But I can't seem to get further than this... Thanks in advance.

What do you mean by globally constant? It certainly will change when $y$ becomes a singular value. Moreover, the actual number (as opposed to total signed number) definitely varies — even among regular values.

You need to learn how to use orientations on $M$ and $N$ to count preimage points with a sign. This is standard basic differential topology. Look at Guillemin and Pollack, for example.

It is constant if your map is a local diffeomorphism.

The first two counterexamples that came to mind. Throughout, $f:M\to N$, $U_f$ will be the set of the regular values of $f$ and $S_f=N\setminus U_f$.

If $M=N=\Bbb{RP}^1$ and $f[x:y]=[x^3-xy^2:y^3]$, then \begin{align}&S_f=\left\{\left[1:0\right], \left[-2\cdot 3^{-3/2}:1\right],\left[2\cdot 3^{-3/2}:1\right]\right\}\\ &U_f\cong \Bbb R\times\{1,2,3\}\\ &\#f^{-1}(p)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }p=[1:0]\\ 2&\text{if }p\in\left\{ \left[-2\cdot 3^{-3/2}:1\right],\left[2\cdot 3^{-3/2}:1\right]\right\}\\ 1&\text{if }p\in \left\{[x:1]\,\middle\vert\, x<-2\cdot 3^{-3/2}\lor x>2\cdot 3^{-3/2}\right\}\\ 3&\text{if }p\in \left\{[x:1]\,\middle\vert\, -2\cdot 3^{-3/2}< x<2\cdot 3^{-3/2}\right\}\end{cases}\end{align}

If $M=N=\Bbb{CP}^1$ and $f[w:z]=[w^2:z^2]$, then \begin{align}&S_f=\left\{\left[1:0\right], \left[0:1\right]\right\}\\ &U_f\cong \Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\\ &\#f^{-1}(p)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }p\in S_f\\ 2&\text{if }p\in U_f\end{cases}\end{align}



Thanks! I think I mistook the 'influence' of connectedness of $N$ and $M$. Would there be a similar statement if the set ${ #f^{-1}(y) }$ or something similar was connected? (If such a thing is even possible)

@Blerp $#f^{-1}(y)$ is a cardinal (at best a natural number), so it's unclear what topology you would put on $\left{#f^{-1}(y),\middle\vert, y\in N\right}$. If the question is what good ideas you could be looking for, my answer is that I don't know.
